# Why is this drawing a box before the button is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, repaint

I'm relatively new to java and I'm just trying to code a GUI that draws a box when a button is pressed. My problem is, my program draws the box before the button is pressed and I don't know how to fix this.

This is my controller class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.* ;


public class TestController extends JFrame {
private JButton enterButton;
private JPanel buttonHolder;
private Container contentPane;
private TestView view;

public TestController() {
    contentPane = getContentPane();
    enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
    buttonHolder = new JPanel();
    buttonHolder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (600, 100));
    contentPane.add(buttonHolder, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    buttonHolder.add(enterButton);

    view= new TestView();       
    view.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (125, 125));
    contentPane.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            view.repaint(); 
        }
    });

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
     TestController bc = new TestController() ;
     bc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
     bc.pack();
     bc.setVisible(true) ;  

}

}
```

This is my view class:

```
import java.awt.* ;     
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.* ;

public class TestView extends JPanel {
public TestView() {}

public void paintComponent( Graphics g ){
    super.paintComponent( g );
    Graphics2D g2= ( Graphics2D ) g;
    Rectangle2D rect= new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 30, 30); 
    g2.setPaint( Color.CYAN );
    g2.fill( rect );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways to do it.

You can for example set the visibility of `TestView` to false until the button is pressed.

```
view.setVisible(false);
```

and in your button's action listener:

```
view.setVisible(true);
```

**Why did you have your problem:**

Every Visual object you create is visible by default.
When you added your object to the board, it was drawn because of that.

This call showed your object: **contentPane.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);**

Comment: Thank you! I still don't understand why it was drawing the box before the button was pressed though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let go of the illusion that you control the paint process in Swing, you don't. Swing uses a passive repaint process which is controlled by the `RepaintManager`, it is this objects responsibility to decide what and when something should be repainted.

`paintComponent` is called as part of the repaint chain on your behalf by the `RepaintManager` and may be called for any number of reasons (many outside of your direct control).

Your code is doing exactly what you told it to.

If you want to change the state of the components painting, then you should probably use some kind of state variable to tell the `paintComponent` if it should paint the rectangle or not...

```
private boolean paintRect = false;

public void paintComponent( Graphics g ){
    super.paintComponent( g );
    if (paintRect) {
        Graphics2D g2= ( Graphics2D ) g;
        Rectangle2D rect= new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 30, 30); 
        g2.setPaint( Color.CYAN );
        g2.fill( rect );
    }
}
```

You would then need to provide some kind of access to the state variable in the `TreeView` class.

```
public void setPaintRect(boolean paint) {
    paintRect = paint;
    repaint();
}
```

Now, in your `actionPerformed` method, you would simply need to set the state...

```
enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        view.setPaintRect(true); // or what ever you want.
    }
});
```

On a side note.  Your `TreeView` should be overriding `getPreferredSize` and returning a suitable size hint for other layout managers.  You've gotten away with it by using `BorderLayout` and manually setting the size of the frame, but `TreeView`'s default size is 0x0.

Take a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

For more details